# Why is my query not returning a field that exists in MySql table?

Tags: php, mysql

Code:

```
$query="SELECT img, pname FROM tracker
WHERE user_id ='$userid'
UNION ALL
SELECT name, other_stuff FROM users
WHERE user_id ='$userid'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error in query".mysql_error());  

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

echo "";

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

    $img= mysql_result($result,$i,"img");
    $pn= mysql_result($result,$i,"pname");
    $name= mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
    $os= mysql_result($result,$i,"other_stuff");

    echo "$img - $pn - $name - $os";

    $i++;
}
```

Using this code, I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: pname not found in MySQL result index 3 in [my page] on line 76.
```

Line 76 refers to `$pn= mysql_result($result,$i,"pname");`

There are same errors for name and other_stuff. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. I hope you have used [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because this looks terrifyingly insecure.

Comment: @tadman I am new to PHP.  I am just testing this out to get a sense of PHP/MySQL and then work on improving security aspects.  What am I doing wrong with the above?

Comment: Enough with this *"I'm just testing this out"* attitude! I suggest you use an up-to-date extension like *mysqli* or *PDO*. Re-writing this all later to use a different API will be much more painful than just doing it from the start.

Comment: What you're doing wrong is writing anything using `mysql_query`. That's a huge mistake. At the **very least** use PDO. Remember, `mysql_query` is going to be removed from PHP, so you either re-write it now before you've made too much of a mess, or you re-write it later when you've got a whole code-base to port.

Comment: Sorry to sound so harsh, but coding like this is difficult, error prone, and very time consuming. In the 1990s this was the only way to fly. Today, using a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) as a foundation would make it a lot easier to get things done.

Answer (score 2):

You want a join, not a union:

```
SELECT img, pname, name, other_stuff 
FROM tracker
JOIN users 
ON users.user_id = tracker.user_id
WHERE tracker.user_id ='$userid'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just realized that's what I needed.  I just came up with that as well but I am getting this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2' at line 4

Comment: JSFiddle is for JavaScript, HTML and CSS. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is the same thing for SQL queries.